# ¿Como actualizar un recycler con un spinner?

Tags: android

Tengo un fragment en el que muestro un Recycler View en donde le mando datos desde una BD y tengo un spinner encima que tiene dependiendo de lo que se selccione; dia semana y tal para mostrar esos datos
El fragment para mandarle datos al adapter es:

```
       fechaSpiner="h";
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    Query query = mFirestore.collection("Ventas");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Ventas> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Ventas>().setQuery(query,Ventas.class).build();
    mAdapter = new VeDiariasAdapater(firestoreRecyclerOptions, getActivity(),contexto,fechaSpiner);

            fecha.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    switch (position){
                        case 0:fechaSpiner="h";break;
                        case 1:fechaSpiner="a";break;
                        case 2:fechaSpiner="s";;break;
                        case 3:fechaSpiner="m";break;
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    rvVeD.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
    return view;
```

y para recibir los datos y seleccionar utilizo en el adapter:

```
       fecha = ventas.getFecha_Ven().toString();
    switch (x){
        case "h":analizador=fecha.substring(0,fecha.indexOf("de")-1);break;
        case "a":analizador=ayer.substring(0,ayer.indexOf("de")-1);break;
        case "s":analizador=fecha.substring(fecha.indexOf("Semana") + 7); break;
        case "m":analizador=fecha.substring(fecha.indexOf("de")+3,fecha.indexOf("del")-1);break;
    }

    if (diahoy.contains(analizador)) {
        final String id = ventasDocument.getId();

        holder.tvNombrev.setText(ventas.getNom_Ven());
}else{
       holder.ej.removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

pero el problema es que como le mando h de dia en el primer caso; se qeuda con el mismo valor aunque se seleccione otro dato; alguien que me pueda ayudar a darle solucion porfvor

Comment: Por que cambias de adapter? al usar setAdapter , te reseta todo el recycler view desde la dimension calculacion.

Comment: en que parte es eso :( no entendí?

Comment: mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    rvVeD.setAdapter(mAdapter);  Eso es incoherente

Comment: El primero es para actualizar el recycler si la bd es actualiazad y el segundo es para enviarle el adpter al recycler

Comment: No se debe hacer eso, actualizas y luego reinicias todo el recyclerview. suficiente con el notifyDataSetChanged para actualizar la vista.

Comment: Pero en ese caso como podria llenar mi Recycler si no le mando mi adapter al mismo?

Comment: Primero se agregar el adapter al recycler setAdapter, luego ya trabajas con tu logica usando solo el adaptaer para actualizacion de los datos.

Comment: El adapter lo pones al crear la vista recyclerview. O en un metodo de creacion en un activity seria oncreate.

Comment: nono si esa es la logica, soloq ue intente ponerlo ahi para ver si me funcionaba o se actualizaba, normalmente va en el onCreateView